# Add protocol to URL after deployment

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deployment, content-builder, email-studio

Panicking. I set up an email with content builder and had multiple people test everything fully before deployment, but now when I click on the link in the final email that deployed to my audience, I get a 404 error because the link in my html didn't have the http:// protocol and salesforce can't redirect it from the cl.s6.exct.net/ domain. Is there anything I can do to fix this in the emails that have been sent out?? I've tried adding the protocol and updating the job link, but that has not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your situation, you can update the static links simply using replace function within the tracking UI under job links. Note: You'd also need a RedirectTo function which provides tracking information for clickable links within an email message.

Example:

```
%%=RedirectTo(Replace('https://www.cl.s6.exct.net/sampleurl/','https://www.cl.s6.exct.net','http://protocol'))=%%
```

**Reference:**

- [Update a Job Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_job_link.htm&type=5)
- [RedirectTo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm)
- [Replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm)